# Determine if a character is alphabetic

Tags: php, validation

Having problems with this.

Let's say I have a parameter composed of a single character and I only want to accept alphabetic characters. How will I determine that the parameter passed is a member of the latin alphabet (`a`–`z`)?

By the way Im using PHP Kohana 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify the question:  what is an *alphabets*?  Maybe you mean an alphabetic character?  Or an alphanumeric character?

Comment: Oh, ok I stand to be corrected. Alphabetic should be the proper term. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the following guard clause at the top of your method:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z]$/", $param)) {
    // throw an Exception...
}
```

If you want to allow upper case letters too, change the regular expression accordingly:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]$/", $param)) {
    // throw an Exception...
}
```

Another way to support case insensitivity is to use the `/i` case insensitivity modifier:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z]$/i", $param)) {
    // throw an Exception...
}
```

Comment: preg_match("/^[a-z]$/i", $param) or use case insensitive

Comment: Your comments are backwards. If preg_match succeeds in matching [a-z], then you should not throw an exception. if(!preg_match(...)) { exception! }

Comment: @Nick Presta: Good catch. I added a `!` to the conditions. Thanks :)

Comment: Regex are fine, but many times you use one, even if trivial, you reinvent the wheel and introduce contact surface for bugs. I'd prefer http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php .

Comment: Um, [that’s almost always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955086/sort-upper-case-just-before-lowercase-key-values-from-a-hash/4958634#4958634).  you want `/^\p{Alphabetic}+$/` instead.

Answer (score 28):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php

```
<?php
    $ch = 'a';
    if (ctype_alpha($ch)) {
        // Accept
    } else {
        // Reject
    }
```

This also takes locale into account if you set it correctly.

**EDIT:** To be complete, other posters here seem to think that you need to ensure the parameter is a single character, or else the parameter is invalid. To check the length of a string, you can use [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen). If `strlen()` returns any non-1 number, then you can reject the parameter, too.

As it stands, your question at the time of answering, conveys that you have a single character parameter somewhere and you want to check that it is alphabetical. I have provided a general purpose solution that does this, and is locale friendly too.

Comment: But what if `$ch` is more than one character long?

Comment: From the manual: _Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text , are alphabetic_  ctype_alpha() accepts a string.

Comment: I know what `ctype_alpha()` does. The OP wants to reject  all input that is more than one character long and your solution doesn't do that.

Comment: The OP says that he has a single character and wants to check that it is alphabetical. He does not mention that he needs to restrict this to a single character. His parameter is already a single character, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I had a different interpretation. I suppose the requirements need to be clarified. Let's talk about it with the OP in tomorrow morning's scrum. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/', $var_vhar);
```

Method will return int value: for no match returns 0 and for matches returns 1.

Comment: Regex are fine, but many times you use one, even if trivial, you reinvent the wheel and introduce contact surface for bugs. I'd prefer php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php

Comment: [A-Z is passé.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955086/sort-upper-case-just-before-lowercase-key-values-from-a-hash/4958634#4958634)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [a-zA-Z] for Unicode.

here are the example working with Unicode,

```
if ( preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/u', 'my text') ) {
    echo 'match';
} else {
    echo 'not match';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help hopefully.This a simple function in php called [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

```
$mystring = 'a'
if (ctype_alpha($mystring))
{
    //Then do the code here.
}
```

Comment: Just for future reference; there were already two answers here that gave information about using `ctype_alpha`, each posted more than 4 years ago. These answers also included more explanation, and integrated the sample into what the OP's code was doing. In general, you should only add an answer to a very old question like this if you have something substantive to add.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]$/',$input_char);
```

The return value of the above function is true if the $input_char contains a single alphabet, else it is false. You can suitably make use of return value.