# perl -pe regex problem

Tags: regex, perl

I use perl to check some text input for a regex pattern, but one pattern doesn't work with `perl -pe`.

Following pattern doesn't work with the command call:

```
s![a-zA-Z]+ +(?:.*?)/(?:.*)Comp-(.*)/.*!$1!
```

I use the linux shell. Following call I use to test my regex:

```
cat test | perl -pe 's![a-zA-Z]+ +(?:.*?)/(?:.*)Comp-(.*)/.*!$1!'
```

File test:

```
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Database.cpp
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Cache/abc.h
```

Result:

```
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Database.cpp
Cache
```

How can I remove the first result?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What shell are you using? What's your input? What's your expected output?

Comment: What the heck is that wacky backslash octal — er, I mean **non-octal** — gunk there?? Sure looks like an encoding issue to me!

Comment: The output is for special characeters ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat input 
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Database.cpp
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Cache/abc.h

$ perl -ne 'print if s![a-zA-Z]+ +(?:.*?)/(?:.*)Comp-(.*)/.*!$1!' input
Cache
```

Answer (score 3):

That last slash after "Comp-(.*)" may be what's doing it. Your file content in the "Database" doesn't have a slash. Try replacing `Comp-(.*)/.*` with `Comp-(.*)[/.].*` so you can match either the subdirectory or the file extension.

Comment: There was a mistake in my data. But why get I the whole line, when not matching?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in last slash character in the regex. Instead of escaping the dot, it is just normal slash character, which is missing from input string.  Try this:

```
s![a-zA-Z]+ +(?:.*?)/(?:.*)Comp-(.*)[./].*!$1!
```

**Edit:** Updated to match new input data and added another option:

On the other hand, your replacement regex might be replaced by something like:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /Comp-(.*?)[.\/]/'
```

Then there is no need to parse full line with whatever it contains.

Comment: It might also not hurt to use `\s+` instead of ` +`.

Comment: There was a mistake in my data. But why get I the whole line, when not matching? What does **\s+**? I never heard it.

Comment: Because you are using s/// operator to do regex-replace. If regex does not match, no replacement is made.

Comment: I **really** hate seeing `[a-z]` hardcode into any problem more recent than the 1960s that isn’t following some RFC that says one must. Perl will someday emit warnings for this. [Here’s why.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955086/sort-upper-case-just-before-lowercase-key-values-from-a-hash/4958634#4958634)

Comment: @tchrist Agree completely, that's why I updated the answer with another option. On the other hand, input data look like Subversion output, so maybe `[a-zA-Z]` is rather `[AUD]`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I want to skip the first data, because I want only to match the folders.

Answer (score 1):

\s match whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) and '+' means one or more characters.  In this case '\s+' would mean search for one or more whitespaces.

```
cat test
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Database.cpp
A   MaintanceGie?\195?\159mannFlock/System/Comp-Cache/abc.h

perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /\w+?\d+?\d+\w+\/\w+\/Comp-(\w+)[\/]/' test
```