# Like query when any words contain

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to the mysql database. I have a search bar that allows the user to type keywords and search.

Here is an example for my query. It works ok if I type `usa` or `apple`, but If I type `usa apple` together. the result is 0. What I'd like is that when the user types 'usa apple', to return the row with apples from the usa (The first row).

```
$search="usa apple";

fruit   country
apple   usa
apple   aus
banana  usa
orange  usa


SELECT * FROM market WHERE fruit LIKE '%$search%' || country LIKE '%$search%'
```

Comment: what if user type "I love usa new york banana"

Comment: if we break every works into array, the query will return I, love, usa, new, york, banana, that will search everything include I, love...

Comment: wow! thx a lots, its really help, i need to do more testing on this. TY!

Comment: I just try "I love usa banana" on google. google only search usa and banana these 2 words. No idea how they filter the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first you need to separate the input search query into individual keywords. In php, you can do this as follows:

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $searchQuery);
```

Then, use the `AND` keyword in the query to retrieve the desired row.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM market WHERE fruit LIKE '%$keywords[0]%' AND country LIKE '%$keywords[1]%'";
```

Since sometimes the order of the keywords might be reversed, you can use an `OR` operator too.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM market WHERE (fruit LIKE '%$keywords[0]%' AND country LIKE '%$keywords[1]%') OR (fruit LIKE '%$keywords[1]%' AND country LIKE '%$keywords[0]%')";
```

If you think the user might use a different delimiter other than a `space` you could use Regular expression to determine if any character that is not alpha-numeric is present. Then, use that character as a delimiter and identify the individual keywords.

[Determine if a character is alphabetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227080/determine-if-a-character-is-alphabetic)

[Edit]:

Another simple thing to do is, use the `OR` statement of MySQL and check if any one condition matches. No need to explode the query.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM market WHERE (fruit LIKE '%$query%' AND country LIKE '%$query%') OR (fruit LIKE '%$query%') OR (country LIKE '%$query%') ";
```

This query will first check if both the keywords are present and then check if the individual keywords are present and return accordingly.

Comment: what if user type apple usa, than the array will place in wrong column

Comment: what if user type usa,apple. I'm thinking using loop for this, is that ok, since we don't know how many words will user type into it

Comment: In such case, you need to perform addition checks using php to determine the delimiter and process according to the number of keywords. Usually, search modules like this will require comparatively larger number of checks and conditions.